# I want to search for a string in an array and want to display key : "value" of string in front end in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular6

For example I am searching for the word "test" in array or object

```
{[email:"test@gmail.com",name:"test"]}
```

I want in the result to be {name:"test"}.

```
search() {
        this.searchValue = this.input.nativeElement.value;
        this.searchModel = this.input_type.nativeElement.value;
        this.globalService.search(this.input.nativeElement.value, this.input_type.nativeElement.value).subscribe((res: IResponse) => {
                    this.resultSearch = res.result;
                    console.log(this.resultSearch)
                    console.log(this.searchValue)
                }
```

Comment: Your array is not a valid json. Did you mean this `[{email:"test@gmail.com"},{name:"test"}]`